# Fail2Ban is unable to block ip after multiple try

Tags: linux, ssh, firewall, rhel5, fail2ban

I have installed fail2ban on my Linux server version **RHEL5.4**. Its not blocking IP after max retry limit as described in jail.conf. When I try to restart the fail2ban  I got following error message.

```
/etc/init.d/fail2ban restart
Stopping fail2ban: [  OK  ]
Starting fail2ban: ERROR  NOK: (2, 'No such file or directory')
[  OK  ]
```

I have tried many more but failed to got solved the above issue. Following is the ssh jail in jail.conf file.

```
[ssh]

enabled  = true
filter   = sshd
action   = iptables[name=SSH, port=ssh, protocol=tcp]
           sendmail-whois[name=SSH, dest=a@exm.com, sender=a@exmp.com, sendername="Fail2Ban"]
logpath  = /var/log/secure
maxretry = 3
```

Any body can suggest where is the issue.?

Answer (score 0):

To configure fail2ban, make a 'local' copy the jail.conf file in /etc/fail2ban

> cd /etc/fail2ban
>
> sudo cp jail.conf jail.local

Try to restart with default configuration also before editing anything.

Comment: set `loglevel = 4` and check error in `/var/log/fail2ban.log` make sure selinux is disabled.

Comment: All are okay but still no solution.